# Hitting a XML API using phonegap?

Tags: mobile, cordova

I am looking at using phonegap to create a mobile app that accesses a xml api, I noticed there is a HTTP class defined in phonegap http://phonegap.pbworks.com/JavaScript-API#http, but I can't seem to find anyone that has used it yet.  Any examples out there or hints/tips on using the http class to access a xml api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the HTTP class nor the JavaScript API for it has been implemented yet on any of the platforms.

You should be able to use the native JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object, aside from maybe in the Blackberry browser.

Comment: yeah looks like XMLHttpRequest (ajax) will do the trick, thanks!